# Is the midwest accent the standard accent in TOEFL and CNN?

Tags: accent

Of late I had somebody told me that midwest accent is the standard accent in TOEFL and CNN. If this is the case, then how to get used to this accent? CNN is a bit too fast for me now, so I want to find an alternative source for accustoming to this accent.

Incidentally, if this question is off-topic, please feel free to tell me directly and I would either delete it or make necessary revisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newscasts from [National Public Radio](http://www.npr.org/programs/) tend to be rather less excited than the commercial networks, and represent a good range of standard US accents. If you want something really slow (and very funny), Garrison Keillor's [Lake Wobegon stories](http://www.garrisonkeillor.com/radio-categories/the-news-from-lake-wobegon/) might suit you.

Comment: Keillor's own accent is rather neutral, but some of the characters in the show's sketches have comically exaggerated [Upper Midwest accents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Midwest_American_English).

Comment: @NateEldredge Quite so, which is why I recommended Keillor's monologues. The Guy Noir pieces and Lives of the Cowboys are generally pretty moderate, too.

Comment: _This American Life_ also speaks reasonably slowly, with occasional dashes of genuine accents from outside the Chicago area.